# If X and Y are independent exponential random variables with parameters λ1 and λ2,How do I express the density function of Z = XY?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

My solution is:

1.calculating the cdf(Cumulative Distribution Function) of Z using the F(Z<z)=F(XY<z), written as F(z).

2.the derivation of F(Z) is just f(z), namely the pdf of Z.

But I failed to get F(z), because the integrand is unintegrable.

And unfortunately, I cannot find other solutions.

Comment: Edit your post using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Secondly, the definition of cdf is $F(Z\leq z)$ . Thirdly, it is not "unintegrable". Rather it has no closed form. Unintegrable means that the integral is not finite.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957135/product-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables) a similar post